# Image formation at surface of water

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

Consider a lake full of water which has an object immersed in it. Now, if an observer was at the surface at a sufficient distance so that the light ray from the object is internally reflected, would he be able to see the object? If not, then why?

Conversely, would the fish see the observer (since the visibility is constrained to a small area)?

Comment: Please tell the reason for downvoting the question

Comment: Are you asking about the condition where the ray propagates *along* the surface, or just the condition where the observer is at an angle where TIR would occur?

Comment: Please tell me about both cases separately. I don't understand the difference between them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's draw an image to show the observer above the lake looking at an object in the lake:

[image: Fish in lake]

where the angles $i$ and $r$ are given by [Snell's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law). You say:

> Now, if an observer was at the surface at a sufficient distance so that the light ray from the object is internally reflected

but there is no position for the observer where they cannot see the fish and likewise the fish can always see the observer. All that happens is that as the distance between the observer and fish increases, so the angle $i \rightarrow \pi/2$, to the observer the fish appears to be nearer and nearer to the surface. This is the well known phenomenon of water appearing to be shallower than it really is.

From the fishes point of view all the light from above the water is compressed into a cone of half angle equal to the critial angle. At values of $r$ greater than the critical angle the fish sees a reflection of the lake bottom.

Comment: So you are saying that I can see the fish near the surface of the water. If that is the case, shouldn't we be able to see the sea floor from the surface of the water?

Comment: @Akshit: yes, when viewed at a shallow angle the sea floor will appear to be near the surface. Of course, in real seas the water isn't clear enough to see the sea floor unless it's an unusually shallow sea.

Answer (score 1):

The person won't see any image provided he's looking through a large enough angle as the light rays don't intersect at the surface but 'appear' to intersect elsewhere (assuming the total reflection of course). And that elsewhere will be visible only when seen from under the surface of water at a proper orientation of course.